# ¿Existe alguna relación entre los dos significados de la palabra "parábola"?

Tags: etimología, significado, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

He estado leyendo acerca de las secciones cónicas y me ha llamado la atención que el significado geométrico de ***parábola*** ("un tipo de línea curva") no parece tener ninguna relación o semejanza con su significado retórico ("una especie de cuento que pretende dejar una enseñanza").

Sin embargo, ambas acepciones comparten la misma etimología: vienen de la palabra griega *parabolé*.

Me gustaría saber a partir de cuál significado original evolucionaron ambas palabras, y si se nota en los significados actuales ese origen (y, por lo tanto, si les queda alguna relación o si ya son palabras totalmente distintas).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Parabolé* viene del griego *para* "a un lado" y el verbo *bállō* "poner" o "arrojar". Lo usó por primera vez Apolonio de Perge (s. I a.E.C.) como término para describir la curva en cuestión. Las secciones cónicas (elipse, parábola e hipérbola) se usaban para resolver ecuaciones cuadráticas por un método llamado de aplicación de áreas, en la cual se comparaban áreas geométricas cubiertas por estas curvas y por rectángulos. Con la parábola se obtenía un resultado sin deficiencia ni exceso, es decir, podía **ponerse a un lado** o compararse la curva con la sucesión de rectángulos que aproximaba el área.

El concepto de *parábola* como cuento o historia proviene del mismo origen trasladado a lo figurativo: "poner a un lado" como sinónimo de comparación o símil. Hablar en parábolas es contar algo utilizando, en vez de términos concretos, figuras que los representan. Asociamos las parábolas a cuentos moralizantes porque para eso se utilizaban.