# ¿Existe alguna relación entre las palabras "elipse" y "elipsis"?

Tags: etimología, significado, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

Una ***elipse*** es un tipo de línea curva cerrada, muy importante por varias razones geométricas y científicas. Por otra parte, una ***elipsis*** es un concepto retórico que se refiere a cuando, por la razón que sea, no aparece una palabra o construcción necesaria en el discurso.

No sólo son palabras parecidas (parónimos), sino que comparten un adjetivo (*elíptico*) y tienen la misma raíz etimológica: la palabra griega *élleipsis*.

Se puede hablar de la *órbita elíptica* de un planeta (la curva que describe en su movimiento) y del *sujeto elíptico* de una oración (el sujeto gramatical que no se dice porque se infiere). Ambos "elipticos" tienen significados que parecen ser totalmente diferentes.

¿Queda alguna remembranza del significado original de estas palabras en el español actual, que nos permita decir que todavía tienen alguna relación; o, al contrario, son palabras totalmente distintas a pesar de su origen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De manera similar a [lo que ocurre con *parábola*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27165/14627), el significado griego de [ἔλλειψις](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%88%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) *élleipsis* es "omisión" o "deficiencia"; viene del verbo *elleípō* "faltar, quedarse corto, omitir". Se usó para nombrar una sección cónica (la que hoy conocemos como *elipse*) que, al usar el método pitagórico de "aplicación de áreas", daba un resultado con un defecto (menor al valor buscado). Al menos esto es lo que he entendido; no termino de visualizar cómo funciona el método.

La palabra griega pasó al latín sin cambios (*ellīpsis*), y con ambos significados, el literal ("omisión") usado luego para la figura retórica y para la gramática, y el matemático.

Pensando en la [respuesta de Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27166/14627), me da la fuerte impresión de que los lexicógrafos de la RAE registraron el uso de *eclipsis* como sinónimo de *elipsis* pero no cayeron en la cuenta de que la etimología era otra, quizá porque se trata de un tema bastante oscuro de la historia de las matemáticas, y porque desde siempre se han tratado a estas curvas como "cónicas", atendiendo a su derivación geométrica a partir de planos que cortan conos, cosa bastante fácil de dibujar y visualizar, con lo cual el motivo de los nombres originales se olvidó.

*Eclipse* proviene del griego ἔκλειψις *ékleipsis* "ausencia, abandono", de ἐκ- *ek-* (cognado del latín *ex-*, "hacia afuera") y λείπω *leípō* "irse, marcharse". Es razonable que se haya usado *eclipsis*, en forma más cercana al original, ya que es un cultismo.

Answer (score 3):

El diccionario de la RAE, en su versión de 1780, nos da una buena pista de que, en realidad, el origen de ambas palabras es algo diferente.

Si buscamos *elipse* encontramos esto:

> ELIPSE, ó ELIPSI. s.f. *Geom.* Figura prolongada contenida de sola una linea curva, la qual procede de la seccion obliqua, hecha en un cono, con un plano que corta sus dos lados.

Y si buscamos *elipsis* encontramos esto:

> ELIPSIS. s.f. V. ECLIPSIS.

Creo que ya imaginas por dónde van los tiros. Busquemos *eclipsis* y encontraremos esto:

> ECLIPSIS. d.f. *Ret.* Figura con que se omite en la oración alguna cosa, que es necesaria para que esté cabal y perfecta. Dícese tambien ELIPSIS.

La verdad es que tiene bastante más sentido que *elipsis* ("ocultación de alguna parte de una frase") se dijera antes *eclipsis*, más emparentada pues con *eclipse* ("ocultación de un astro"). La palabra *eclipsis* ha estado de hecho en el DLE hasta 1992, aunque con la marca de "desusado".

En todo caso, incluso el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, que también recoge *eclipsis*, dice que incluso en griego algunos decían *elypsis*, y que por tanto por entonces también se usaba *elipsis* en castellano, aunque menciona que *eclipsis* era más usado "porque quiere decir falta o trabajo".

Nótese por último que la propia palabra *eclipsis* era la usada para los eclipses durante los siglos XIII al XVII:

> *De saber tomar las longuezas de las uillas por los eclipsis lunares.* (1277)

Aunque a partir del siglo XVI comenzó a usarse también *eclipse*, *eclypse* o *eclypsi*.