# ¿Existe alguna relación entre las palabras "hipérbole" e "hipérbola"?

Tags: etimología, significado, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

Por un lado, una ***hipérbola*** es un tipo de línea curva abierta, una de las tres secciones cónicas. Y por otra parte, una ***hipérbole*** es una figura retórica que consiste en exagerar lo que se dice.

El adjetivo *hiperbólico* puede aplicarse en ambos casos. Por ejemplo, puede hablarse del *plano hiperbólico* en geometría, y de un *lenguaje hiperbólico* en retórica. Ambos "hiperbólicos" no parecen tener ninguna relación, a pesar de que comparten la raíz etimológica griega *hyperbolé*.

¿Todavía se puede distinguir alguna relación entre ambas palabras, o ya se independizaron totalmente de su significado etimológico original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este caso sí que hay un remanente de coincidencia en los significados de ambas palabras, aunque ya en latín se distinguieran ambas:

> **[hipérbola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KQcH2y4)**
>
> Del lat. *hyperbŏla*, y este del gr. *ὑπερβολή hyperbolḗ*.
>
> **[hipérbole](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KQeGz9i)**
>
> Del lat. *hyperbŏle*, y este del gr. *ὑπερβολή hyperbolḗ*.

La palabra griega *hyperbolḗ* significa "exceso, exageración". Sabemos que una hipérbole es una "exageración de una circunstancia, relato o noticia". Y una [exageración](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HAQG8hk) es un "concepto, hecho o **cosa que traspasa [excede] los límites** de lo justo, verdadero o razonable". Por tanto tenemos el concepto de *exceso* en la hipérbole. ¿Y en la hipérbola? Pues resulta que una hipérbola es una "**curva cuyo plano excede** en inclinación la de la superficie del cono cortado por él".

Encontramos pues el mismo concepto de "exceso" en ambas palabras, aunque aplicado de formas diferentes.

Answer (score 8):

Como con *[parábola](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27165/14627)* y *[elipse](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27172/14627)*, el nombre de la sección cónica llamada *hipérbola* le fue dado por Apolonio de Perge basándose en el resultado que daban estas curvas al utilizarlas para calcular con el método pitagórico de "aplicación de áreas". La parábola daba un resultado balanceado, la elipse uno con defecto, la hipérbola uno con exceso.

El griego ὑπερβολή *hyperbolḗ* significa precisamente "exceso, exageración"; la raíz es un verbo que significa "poner por encima, arrojar por encima". Tanto la curva *hipérbola* como la figura retórica *hipérbole* derivan de esta palabra griega.

Comment: (+1) fascinating answer, I never knew that in all the time I have known about conic sections.

Comment: ¡Interesante! No por nada estaba la relación semántica escondida.